# Creating a file and writing contents into it in Dynamics Business central (AL)

Tags: azure-storage, dynamics-crm-webapi, dynamics-business-central

I am trying to create a file on azure storage using Dynamics Business Central and then trying to write a string into the file. I am not able to create  the file Can anyone help me in this regard.

My Sample code is

```
cha := 13;
    msVersion := '02-14-2014';
    MethodType := 'CreateFile';
    keyss := 'i0PNZ6Ykse7oSSfUzFeA36rQf5wybQWh5Jol0NRM4sal4s8B3ipkjvfzcsP8';
    //contenttype := 'This is sample text.';
    //contentLength := StrLen(contenttype);
    dateInRfc1123Format := CurrentDateTime;
    //canonicalizedHeaders := 'x-ms-date:' + FORMat(dateInRfc1123Format) + Format(cha) + 'x-ms-version:02-02-2019';
    requestMethod := 'PUT';
    urlPath := 'lables/' + 'tre11.csv';
    canonicalizedResource := '/bcstorage/labes/tre11.csv';
    canonicalizedHeaders := 'x-ms-content-length:1024' + Format(cha) + 'x-ms-date:' + FORMat(dateInRfc1123Format) + Format(cha) + 'x-ms-type:file' + Format(cha) + 'x-ms-version:' + msVersion;
    stringToSign := (requestMethod + Format(cha) + Format(cha) + Format(cha) + Format(cha) + Format(cha) + Format(cha) + Format(cha) + Format(cha) +
    Format(cha) + Format(cha) + Format(cha) + Format(cha) + canonicalizedHeaders + canonicalizedResource);


    authorizationHeader := 'SharedKey bc365storage:' + EncryptionManagement.GenerateBase64KeyedHashAsBase64String(stringToSign, keyss, 2);
    Message((authorizationHeader));
    request.SetRequestUri('https://bcstorage.file.core.windows.net/labes/tre11.csv');
    //request.GetHeaders(RequestHeader);
    request.Method := requestMethod;
    RequestHeader.Add('x-ms-date', FORMat(dateInRfc1123Format));
    RequestHeader.Add('x-ms-version', msVersion);
    RequestHeader.Add('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
    RequestHeader.Add('Accept-Charset', 'UTF-8');
    //RequestHeader.Add('Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=utf-8');
    if MethodType = 'CreateFile' then begin
        RequestHeader.Add('x-ms-content-length', '1024');
        RequestHeader.Add('x-ms-type', 'file');
    end;

    client.Get('https://bcstorage.file.core.windows.net/labes/tre11.csv', hhtpres);
    hhtpres.Content.ReadAs(res);
    Message(res);
    test := client.Send(request, hhtpres);
```

But i get wrong response and i am not able to create the file too.

Comment: Could you please tell me your error?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidHeaderValue</Code><Message>The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
RequestId:a83d16a3-801a-0042-36dc-c98333000000
Time:2020-01-13T06:44:31.7115581Z</Message><HeaderName>x-ms-version</HeaderName><HeaderValue /></Error>

Comment: @Jim Xu  i get the above error.

Comment: According to your error and code  you provided,  the value of the ```x-ms-version``` is wrong. It should be like ```2014-02-14```. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/protocol-version-support-for-.net-client-library-versions.

Comment: Besides, could you please tell me which language you use? Nodejs, .Net or python?

Comment: i am working on Dynamics business Central (AL language).

Comment: Do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
RequestHeader.Add('x-ms-date', FORMat(dateInRfc1123Format));
```

Formats your date based on your server's region settings, use it like this to assert proper filter all the time:

```
RequestHeader.Add('x-ms-date', Format(dateInRfc1123Format,0,9));
```

This will format your data to XML style aka YYY-MM-DD